# BooleanToVisibilityConverter with checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, converters

I am trying to hide the grid, controlled by the checkbox. Currently, when I use the box nothing happens. I cannot figure out why. Everything I have found online is exactly what I have.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--upper window..-->
    <CheckBox x:Name="show" Grid.Row="1" IsChecked="False">Display Preview with Sliders?</CheckBox>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" 
          Visibility="{Binding ElementName=show, Path=isChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
        <!--what I want to hide-->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What's happening, and what do you *want* to happen? Please tell us the exact problem you're having.

Comment: @BigTrev8, Download snoopwpf.codeplex.com and learn how to use it. Invaluable tool for solving issues like binding errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Property names are case sensitive. Replace **`isChecked`** with **`IsChecked`** in your binding.

```
Visibility="{Binding ElementName=show, Path=IsChecked,
                     Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"
```

Comment: Wow, This is why I ask.. because it is always the little things I miss. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah happens sometimes. Glad to help you.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Path=IsChecked
```

Even XAML is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

I advice to use a DataTrigger

```
 <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBoxStyle}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=show,Path=IsChecked,}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```